# AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, spring-boot

My User super class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class User implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Role role;

    other attributes ...
```

Here my role entity:

```
@Entity
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "role", targetEntity = User.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

    another attributes ...
```

i have this subclass of the user class:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class AUser extends User {
...
}
```

another subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class BUser extends User {
     ....
}
```

Here is my exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.x.y.model.Role.users[com.x.y.model.User]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at com.x.y.XApplication.main(XApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.x.y.model.Role.users[com.x.y.model.User]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1191) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:794) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:719) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1655) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1623) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:373) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:362) ~[spring-orm-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1642) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1579) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
```

Can someone tells me what is wrong in my code?

Comment: Hi, from the JavaEE documentation: "Mapped superclasses can’t be targets of entity relationships". So  private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>(); is in my opinon not legal. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html#bnbqp

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. would you please post your entity code to understand how it worked for you. I have used annotation MappedSuperClass on my abstract class User and annotation Entity on child classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make User an entity instead of MappedSuperClass. If you make User an abstract class there will still not be any table in the database.

However I would like to warn you about using TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance in this particular case. TABLE_PER_CLASS gives better performance (when selecting a specific use of a known type), but since you only authenticate a user ones per session, performance should not matter.

I'm working on a system with 3 types of user identity and TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance (Retrospectively it should have been JOINED inheritance). The problem is that if User has a userName property and you want to do type-ahead you need to search 3 tables instead of one (if each different User type has references to different entities, it can be much worse). In the end we ended up having to add a view to the database, because it was close to impossible to write the query we needed to make a fast searchable UI, because we use the wrong inheritance strategy.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is stated there. `Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.x.y.model.Role.users` This is because you are using mapping in a `@MapppedSuperClass`. Such classes are not mapped in to a table by the Java persistence provider.

Comment: i known, but it is someway to do it without create the user entity in the database?

Comment: Using the `@MappedSuperClass` on a class will not create an entity/ a table in the database so in your case there will not be `User` table but you would need to remove the mapping in that class